# Magento 2.2 установка на Windows 10 Open Server

Tags: cms, windows-10, openserver, magento

Уже который раз ставлю **Magento2** на локальный сервер **Open Server** (**Win10**) и сталкиваюсь с большим кол-вом проблем:

1. Если распаковать Magento2.zip в папку /domains и назначить её имя magento2 и попробовать запустить, то в итоге я имею ошибку такого вида -

> Server error! 
>   
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. 
>   
> Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
>   
> **Error 500**

2. Решил я этот вопрос удалением файла **.htaccess**, дошёл до раздела установки и она больше 0% никак не шла, решил данную проблему созданием config/path.txt, так же вписав туда пару строк:

> C:/Program Files/nodejs
>   
> C:/Users/Имя пользователя/AppData/Roaming/npm
>   
> Информация с источника - https://web4pro.net/blog-news/how-to-install-magento-2-on-windows-10-using-local-openserver/

3. После установки Grunt, и Gulp в терминале Open Server дошёл до раздела установки и тут опять столкнулся с тем что в логах всё в полном порядке, но установка прерывается, решил это перезагрузкой страницы. Вроде бы CMS установилась, вижу окошко Sucess, пытаюсь зайти на страницу и вижу вот такое
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Я ньюфаг и толкового что-то найти на др. инфо-ресурсах не смог, уже мозг перегружен от CMS Magento / Уже каждый коллега мне толкует о том что мне стоит перейти на Linux, но я не могу из-за траты времени на изучение большого кол-ва материала. / Надеюсь что и кому-то это в дальнейшем поможет разобраться.

Comment: Magento 2 не поддерживает форточки.
Пробуй Вагрант(https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers#how-to-install) или докер(https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox)

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой же проблемой как и вы, но получилось решить ее. Проблема при установке у вас скорее всего заключается в том что вы подключаете Apache вместе с Ngings. Его не надо устанавливать в модулях:
[image: Мои настройки]

Скидываю вам мои настройки OpenServer-a.
А на счет второго пункта вам нужна команда: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f. Она подтягивает в папку pub недостающие файлы, из-за которых у вас в консоли и сыпятся ошибки.

Comment: Да я уже давно решил данную проблему просто перейдя на более удобный xampp, а насчёт Apache конфигурации у меня стояла без ngix, только PHP-7-x64. Так же со стилями тоже разобрался, в FAQ Magento 2.2 нашёл все ответы, только вот про флаг -f постоянно забывал.
Спасибо вам за ответ! :)